# REST API - probe error

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api, search-criteria

[image]how to get orders that are older than 1 hour from the current time. When I type NOW() -60, I get an internal error, log file never existed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate the difference manually, then pass that calculated date in created at for filter records. For example

```
// get current time - 1 hour
$time = date(
    "Y-m-d H:i:s",
    (time() - 3600)
);

// then use it as a filter
(...)
->addFieldToFilter(
   'created_at',
   [
      'gteq' => $time
   ]
);
```

This logic is for getting order collection anywhere but for your case what you can pass in API to get records.

First, think of identifying 1 hour cap from the current time after that Use **created_at** field to get an order in this range. your request will be same but you just need to pass the calculated date in value in the mentioned api.

I hope this will help you to get what you need.

Comment: I want make probe, which use only GET URL, where should I put the code to make the url with variable

Comment: David you have to pass calculated date in created at field with gteq condition. If you try you would get results surely

Comment: Take any date and substrate as per this formala and paste in api request you will not get this error.